# how to sort and append the list of words to an empty list in python

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to write a python code that reads a bunch of lines from a text file and then splits the lines into words. Then for each word, it checks to see if the word is already present in the list, if not present then adds to it and finally sorts the list and prints the final list. This is what i have written so far.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
new = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    word = line.split()
    for w in word:
        if w not in new:
            final = new.append(w)
            result = final.sort()
    print result
```

But i am getting the below error..
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort' on line 12`

Don't know why? Any help?

Thanks
Upendra

Comment: `.append` doesn't return anything.

Comment: You just need `new.append(...)`. You don't need `final = new.append(...)`. Then simply sort `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname) as fh: #  use with to automatically close the file
    final = []
    new = [x.rstrip().split() for x in fh] # strip and split into sublists of words
    for ele in new: 
        for word in ele: # for every word in each sublist
            if not word in final: # if word not already in final then add word
                final.append(word)
    final.sort()  # sort 
    print final
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `append()` and `sort()` are in-place and don't return anything.

You can rewrite

```
        final = new.append(w)
        result = final.sort()
```

like so:

```
        final = new + [w]
        result = sorted(final)
```

Note that the sorting can (and should be) moved out of the loop: it's quite costly and doesn't need to be done for every word.

Finally, I'd suggest using sets instead of lists. They automatically ensure uniqueness, will result in simpler code, and are generally more performant for this sort of use case.

Answer (score 0):

A sorted list of all words in a file:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname) as fh:
    result = sorted(set(fh.read().split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the fact that the .append() method just appends to your existing list and does not return anything. So you should rewrite your code as:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
new = list()
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    word = line.split()
    for w in word:
        if w not in new:
            new.append(w)
    new.sort() #rather than sorting it in each iteration, why not just sort it at the end?
    print new
```

Comment: Please recheck. I forgot to amend the sort method.